# Django show string isn't working

Tags: python, django

I'm passing the manual of [Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03.html)

I set up my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from main.views import hello

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

The file sit in subfolder called : `main`.

I set up urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```

When I'm going to: `http://localhost:8000//main/hello` or `http://localhost:8000/`

I see:

> NameError at /main/hello name 'hello' is not defined

but if I change my views.py to:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
)
```

then in `http://http://localhost:8000/` I see :

```
It worked!
Congratulations on your first Django-powered page.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

These are my project files:

[image]

how do I solve this?

Comment: thx. now the error has changed to : `Page not found (404)`

Comment: Are you accessing it on `127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`? `127.0.0.1:8000/` will return 404, since there is no view associated with this url.

Comment: im accessing `127.0.0.1:8000/main/hello`

Comment: This is not correct. In your `urls.py` you pointed that `url(r'^hello/$', hello)`, e.g. url `hello/` should be handled by `hello` view. So you should access it on `127.0.0.1:8000/hello/`. If you want it on different url, you should change `urls.py`.

Comment: The site you linked to is extremely outdated (it's for Django 1.4 the current version is 1.8). You should try following [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) on the Django site since the version that gets installed with `pip install django` is 1.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import views inside the urls page.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from main.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```

Now you can access it through:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/hello
```

Comment: is this the same urls file specified in the `settings.py` file?

Comment: @user2641077 You should access `127.0.0.1:8000/hello`. Not `/main/hello`

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `hello` from `views.py`.

`urls.py` will look like this.

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from main.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```